# Transpose with comments using moveTo

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to transpose a sheet with comments, unfortunately comments are not not transposed when using the past as function or the =TRANSPOSE(yy:xx) formula. The only way i know is .moveTo(), but other solutions are welcome to.

This would work, but the range of my sheet is A1:BQ24

```
function transpose() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("original");
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("target");
  sheet.getRange("A1").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("A1"));
  sheet.getRange("B1").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("A2"));
  sheet.getRange("C1").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("A3"));
  ...
  sheet.getRange("A2").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("B1"));
  sheet.getRange("B2").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("B2"));
  sheet.getRange("C2").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("B3"));
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Transpose with moveTo**

This is real slow but it does move the comments correctly.

```
function transpose() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Original");
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("Target");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();//selects all the data on the sheet
  for(var r=1;r<=sh.getLastRow();r++) {
    for(var c=1;c<=sh.getLastColumn();c++) {
      sh.getRange(r,c).moveTo(tsh.getRange(c,r));
    }
  }
}
```